# Pulling multiple fields from database using forms and php

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a database with multiple rows with various fields.

I have a form that contains a drop down list.
The drop down list displays one of the database fields (field_name) for each row in the database.

When the user selects the desired entry hits SUBMIT, that value is passed to the results.php page and can be used via $_POST.

All of this currently works.

I would like a way to send the rest of the row's fields that correspond to the row of the selected field (not just the "field_name") from the database along with what is selected from the drop down menu.

For instance, if I have a database with rows with a fields named "name", "date", and "age", I would like to have all the database rows "name"s appear in the drop down list and once submitted, pass that particular name's "date" and "age" on to the results.php for use on that page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Drop Down Test</title>
</head>

<body style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 11px;">

<?php

//Variables for connecting to database.
$hostname = "abcd";
$username = "abcd";
$dbname = "abcd";
$password = "abcd";
$usertable = "abcd";

//Connecting to database
$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to connect to database!");
$db = mysql_select_db($dbname);

$query = "SELECT * FROM abcd";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

?>

<h2>Drop Down Test Form</h2>

<p>Please fill out the form below and click submit.</p>

<form action="results.php" method="POST">

    <p>Drop Down Test:
        <select name='event'>
        <!-- Drop down -->
        <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<option>' . $row['field_name']. '</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"><p>

</form>
```

Comment: Warning! http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php. Learn [PHP the right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

Comment: This did the trick (in results.php):
`$query = "SELECT * from abcd where field_name='$_POST[event]'";`
`$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`
`$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);`
`echo "id: " . $row[0] . "<br/>";`
`echo "field_name: " . $row[1] . "<br/>";`
`etc...`

Comment: Thanks! Now that I have it working the "wrong" way, i will try to make it work the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick (in results.php):

```
<?php

$hostname = "****";
$username = "****";
$dbname = "****";
$password = "****";
$usertable = "abcd";

$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to connect to database!");
$db = mysql_select_db($dbname);

//it was this SQL query that was the key, namely the WHERE statement
$query = "SELECT * from abcd where field_name='$_POST[event]'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 

echo "id: " . $row[0] . "<br/>";
echo "field_name: " . $row[1] . "<br/>";
//etc...

//try to throw the individual results into variables
$variable = $row[1];

echo "Check to see that the variable was passed a value: " . $variable . "<br />"; 
echo "Check to see that form selection carried over: " . $_POST['event'] . "<br />"; 

?>
```

I realize this is not the "up-to-date" way of doing things and I will now try to get everything "modernized".

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

you should put a `value` on your option like this:

```
echo '<option value = "'.$row['field_name'].'" name = "">' . $row['field_name']. '</option>';
```

then you can access it by `$_POST['event'];`

**UPDATE**

getting all the values from the select, you can use `$_SESSION` variables to pass it to the other php.file.

Comment: the `$_POST['event'];` works on the results.php page - it receives the value of the selection of the drop down. I want to pass the rest of the values associated with the row that the selected value is in.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //  First of all, I advice you to connect via PDO, or at least msqli, because mysql_query is depreciated.
  //  To connect with database you need:
  DEFINE("USER", "root"); 
  DEFINE("DBNAME", "test"); 
  DEFINE("DBPASSWORD", ""); 
  DEFINE("DBHOST", "localhost");
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBNAME,USER,DBPASSWORD,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));


   //The query:
   $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name,age,date FROM test");
   $sth->execute();

  //the drop down form
    echo '<form action="results.php" method="POST">
    <select name="event"><option value=0></option>';
    while ($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { extract($result);
    echo '<option value="date:'.$date.'-age:'.$age.'"/>'.$name.'</option>'; 
    echo '</select>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"><p>
    </form>';
    }

//the event in the records.php by clicking submit
if(isset($_POST['event'])){
echo 'name:',$name'-date:',$date,'-$age',$age;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now that I have it working the "wrong" way, i will try to make it work the correct way.